# Catch all route in actix-web v4

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm looking for a way to write a catch all route in actix web. What naturally makes sense to me would be to have a `"/*"` route, but this gives me an error about tail segments.

```
async fn not_found() -> impl Responder {
    "404"
}

HttpServer::new(|| {
  App::new()
    .service(Files::new("/", "./").index_file("index.html")
    .route("/*", web::get().to(not_found))
  })
  .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
  .run()
  .await
```

*actix_router::resource Tail segments must have names. Consider `.../{tail}*`. This may become a panic in the future.*

I have looked at the actix-web docs and can't find anything. I tried several things including `web::scope` and empty routes, but as actix web says, if the route isn't found, it responds with a 404 code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I used something like this to catch all routes

```rs
#[get("/images/{tail:.*}")]
async fn show(
    request: HttpRequest,
    path: web::Path<String>,
    data: web::Data<AppState>,
) -> impl Responder { }
```

and here is the link in the documentation where I've found about `{tails:.*}`
https://actix.rs/docs/url-dispatch#resource-pattern-syntax

Answer (score 1):

just use the default_service()

```rust
HttpServer::new(|| {
      App::new()
        .service(Files::new("/", "./").index_file("index.html")
        .default_service(web::to(not_found))
      })
      .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
      .run()
      .await
```